# How to recall a list using Shared Preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have managed to reload the list item in a list when the activity call's it's onStop() method. Here I want to store what's generated by pressing a button. If you have read my previous few posts you will know what's happening but this is a different question.

Using my code:

```
listLimit = listItems.size() - 1;

                for( int i = 0; i < listLimit; i++ )
                {
                    storeList[i] = listItems.get( i ).toString();
                    tempDataStore = storeList[i];
                    editor.putString( DATA,tempDataStore );

                }
                editor.commit();
```

I store the values of the storeList. I know that the way it's done above will basically overwrite the tempDataStore every time it iterates through. Which means when it's recalled in the onCreate() method only the last value of the list will be loaded. So how do I fix this? How can I uniquely identify each list item without creating a new String variable for each?

---

UPDATE

I kinda of sorted it by changing the key on and keeping the value. When I add them like this:

```
listItems.add( 0, settings.getString(  DATA+"0",tempDataStore ) );
```

It works. But when I try to do the same thing in a for loop, like so:

```
for( int i = 0; i < listLimit; i++ )
            {
                listItems.add( i, settings.getString(  DATA+""+i,tempDataStore ) );
            }
```

Noting happens. Why so?

Comment: Nothing happens.. you mean.. getting error.. or the list remains empty?

Comment: I determined the reason - it was because listLimit was actually equal to zero therefore the loop would never start. So to rectify this I stored the size of the list and recalled it in the for loop. I'll post what i did soon - I can't submit my own answer because I have less than 100 reputation points :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I determined the reason - it was because listLimit was actually equal to zero therefore the loop would never start. So to rectify this I stored the value of the list like so:

```
listLimit = listItems.size() - 1;
// Place size of list into storage
editor.putInt( "LIST_SIZE",listLimit );
```

And then recalled it to the start of the for loop here:

```
    // Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "list size: "+settings.getInt( "LIST_SIZE",listLimit ),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    for( int i = 0; i < settings.getInt( "LIST_SIZE",listLimit ); i++ )
    {
        listItems.add( i, settings.getString(  DATA+""+i,tempDataStore ) );
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Hope this helps whoever

Answer (score 1):

This code will put all Strings from listItems into the preferences

```
    edit.putInt("count", listItems.size());
    for (int i = 0; i< listItems.size(); i++){
        edit.putString(String.valueOf(i), listItems.get(i));
    }
    edit.apply();
```

You can read them like this

```
    int count = sPrefs.getInt("count", 0);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        list.add(sPrefs.getString(String.valueOf(i), ""));
    }
```